# Get text from div without any tags and special characters

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have an html file with many different structures of text in div tags. The only thing I want to is to get text inside these tags, but without tags, newlines etc.

For example this html div:

```
<div class="textNahlad">
     <i>Informácie pre záujemcu:</i>
     <br>
    Výberový pohovor je potrebné vopred dojednať telefonicky
     <br>
</div>
```

but it can be also:

```
<div class="textNahlad">
         <b>Informácie pre záujemcu:</b>
         <br>
         <br>
         <br>
        <i>Výberový pohovor je potrebné vopred dojednať telefonicky</i>
         <br>
</div>
```

So the result would be: `Informácie pre záujemcu: Výberový pohovor je potrebné vopred dojednať telefonicky`

I'm curious whether is there a function in Python/BS4 which can return only the text without tags and newlines and other mess.

`find.('div',class_="textNahlad")` does not work

EDIT: I tried to do it using .contents and for each content check, whether is it a text or tag, if tag, then get text, but it does not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `stripped_strings` attribute as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html1 = '''<div class="textNahlad">
     <i>Informácie pre záujemcu:</i>
     <br>
    Výberový pohovor je potrebné vopred dojednať telefonicky
     <br>
</div>'''

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html1)

html2 = '''<div class="textNahlad">
         <b>Informácie pre záujemcu:</b>
         <br>
         <br>
         <br>
        <i>Výberový pohovor je potrebné vopred dojednať telefonicky</i>
         <br>
</div>'''

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html2)

>>> print ' '.join(soup1.stripped_strings)
Informácie pre záujemcu: Výberový pohovor je potrebné vopred dojednať telefonicky

>>> print ' '.join(soup2.stripped_strings)
Informácie pre záujemcu: Výberový pohovor je potrebné vopred dojednať telefonicky

>>> ' '.join(soup1.stripped_strings) == ' '.join(soup2.stripped_strings)
True
```

The last line shows that although the whitespace (`<br>`) is different in the input, the text is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

content = """
<div class="textNahlad">
         <b>Informácie pre záujemcu:</b>
         <br>
         <br>
         <br>
         <i>Výberový pohovor je potrebné vopred dojednať telefonicky</i>
         <br>
</div>
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
for string in soup.strings:
    if string.strip():
        print string.strip(),
```

Comment: This produces different results for the 2 HTML samples - the number of spaces between "záujemcu:" and "Výberový" varies. You can use `' '.join([s.strip() for s in soup.strings if s.strip()])` to correct that, but it is clumsy.

Answer (score 0):

I think bs4's [`get_text`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) method should work fine. You can then process the result using some regex to remove any extra whitespace.

```
import re

div = soup.find('div', class_='textNahlad')

text = div.get_text()
# '\nInformácie pre záujemcu:\n\n\n\nVýberový pohovor je potrebné vopred dojednať telefonicky\n\n'

result = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', text).strip()
# 'Informácie pre záujemcu: Výberový pohovor je potrebné vopred dojednať telefonicky'
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you really *should* use a proper parsing library like lxml or BeautifulSoup to do this, but it can easily be done using a couple of regexes and string methods.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf_8 -*- 

import re

src = '''
<div class="textNahlad">
     <i>Informácie pre záujemcu:</i>
     <br>
    Výberový pohovor je potrebné vopred dojednať telefonicky
     <br>
</div>
<div class="textNahlad">
         <b>Informácie pre záujemcu:</b>
         <br>
         <br>
         <br>
        <i>Výberový pohovor je potrebné vopred dojednať telefonicky</i>
         <br>
</div>
'''

flags = re.DOTALL
#Capture div content
pdiv = re.compile(r'<div [^>]*?>(.*?)</div>', flags)
#Find remaining tags
ptag = re.compile(r'<[^>]*?>', flags)

def main():
    divs = pdiv.findall(src)
    for i, d in enumerate(divs):
        parts = [s.strip() for s in ptag.split(d)]
        text = ' '.join(s for s in parts if s)
        print "%d:\n%s\n" % (i, text) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**output**

```
0:
Informácie pre záujemcu: Výberový pohovor je potrebné vopred dojednať telefonicky

1:
Informácie pre záujemcu: Výberový pohovor je potrebné vopred dojednať telefonicky
```

This code doesn't handle HTML entities, but that's not too hard to add.